# JSF EclipseLink - Não consigo gravar informações no banco de dados MySQL

Tags: jsf, jsp, eclipse-link

Estou utilizando JSF numa matéria da faculdade e o professor passou uma atividade. Mas eu não estou conseguindo gravar informações de um formulário. A conexão é feita, eu consigo realizar até consultas em JPQL direto do Netbeans, mas quando tento gravar informações inseridas por um formulário aparece o seguinte erro:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long Error Code: 0

Estou usando o conector Java v5.1.47. Quando tento utilizar um conector mais atualizado não consigo realizar a conexão com o banco de dados. Mesmo com o MySQL configurado para não usar criptografia na senha root. Porque quando utilizei, a conexão não era realizada por causa dessa criptografia.

Atualização

Aqui está o meu persistence.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="RestManagerPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/RestManager</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

E aqui está o DAOHelper, onde ocorre o erro:

```
*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package DAO;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 *
 * @author leand
 */
public class DAOHelper {
    public EntityManager getEM(){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RestManagerPU");
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

O erro ocorre na linha:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RestManagerPU");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente consegui descobrir qual o problema. Por algum motivo o driver JDBC não funciona com o MySQL 8, mesmo o driver 8.0.12. Instalei o MySQL 5.7 e para a conexão utilizei o driver 5.1.47, agora está funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo log do seu erro parece ser um erro de tipo (type).

O Java parece não estar conseguindo transformar uma variável tipo `BigInteger` para tipo `Long` automaticamente. Provavelmente é algum campo do formulário, mas o log não mostra qual seria.

Você vai ter que checar os dados que está inserindo no banco de dados e transformar (cast) para os tipos adequados.

Se está usando o MySQL, provavelmente deve usar [java.math.BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) para transformar `BigInteger` em `Long`.

Veja a tabela 5.1 em [Java, JDBC and MySQL Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) para mais informações sobre as conversões possíveis.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas o objeto Usuarios tem todos os atributos String, eu os criei por engenharia reserva pelo próprio Netbeans. Então os tipos dos atributos condizem com as colunas do banco de dados.

Comment: Olhei aqui na depuração e o erro não ocorre na hora de gravar os dados no banco de dados, ocorre ao tentar criar a conexão

Comment: Sim, ele fala que não conseguiu conectar PORQUÊ não conseguiu fazer o cast da variável. "Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long". Precisaria ver como você processa os dados do formulário e tenta inserir os mesmos no BD. É ali que deve estar o problema.